# Duplicate data in my sql

Tags: java, android, mysql

```html
<?php
require "conn.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry= "insert into employee_data (name, surname, age, username, password) values ('$name', '$surname', '$age', '$username', '$password')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
 echo "Insert Successfull";
}
else{
echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

When I proceed my registration request in my android APP, I got 2 duplicate records in my SQL. Why that happens? This is my background worker.And mine register main java file. I did everything and cant find my error. I figured out that problem is in my background worker. But I cant find it myself, so please help.

```
public class Backgroundworker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Backgroundworker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "https://1/login.php";
        String register_url = "https://1/register.php";
        String get_geolocation = "https://1/location.php";
        if (type.equals("login")){
            /*KOROCHE TYT CONNECT NIZE*/
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];

                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null ){
                    result += line;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else  if (type.equals("register")) {
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String surname = params[2];
                String age = params[3];
                String username = params[4];
                String password = params[5];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("surname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(surname, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("age", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(age, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else  if (type.equals("geo")){
                try {
                    String longitude = params[1];
                    String latitude = params[2];
                    String time = params[3];
                    URL url = new URL(get_geolocation);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("longitude","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(longitude,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("latitude","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(latitude,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("time","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(time,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String result="";
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null ){
                        result += line;

                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("LoginStatus");




    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = 600;
        lp.height = 500;
        lp.x=-170;
        lp.y=100;
        alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.keknew.map_serv;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name, surname, age, username, password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
        surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsurname);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etage);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
    }

    public void OnReg(View view) {
        String str_name = name.getText().toString();
        String str_surname = surname.getText().toString();
        String str_age = age.getText().toString();
        String str_username = username.getText().toString();
        String str_password = password.getText().toString();
        String type = "register";

        Backgroundworker backgroundworker = new Backgroundworker(this);
        backgroundworker.execute(type, str_name, str_surname, str_age, str_username, str_password);

    }


}
```

Comment: What does `register.php` contain?

Comment: Added register.php in my question